# Ways to resolve circular dependency in Angular?

Tags: angular, circular-dependency, angular15

I have two components with a shared service, both of the components will be calling each other's methods of `ngOnInit()` because if first one is changed then second needs to be updated and vice versa.

I have tried to call each components into one another but there is a circular dependency error. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Component should not call each other methods directly. You can use `Input/Output` or `rxjs Subject` to emit change from one component via a shared service and subscribe in other one and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Within that shared services you should create a subject, which will facilitate state sharing across components, something like this:

```js
private subject = new Subject();
 
send(message: any) {
    this.subject.next({message);
}

get(): Observable {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

One component will send e massage, the other will receive it by subscribing using get method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a subscription inside the ngOnInit() methods and emit an event from the other component whenever update happens. No need to call component inside each other.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployees();  
  }
  

  getEmployees() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees()
    .subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
  }}
```

Comment: I emmitted an event ```this.refresh.emit("refreshed");``` and it isn't working, the rest of the work like subscribing has already been done

Comment: Move this refresh to common service between both the components and emit/subscribe from there. Example below:

common.service.ts: (create an event here)
refresh: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();

Component 1: (Emit from first component)
commonService.refresh.emit();

Comonent 2: (Subsscribre from here)
this.commonService.refresh.subscribe((data) => {
     code here
});